# How to transform change comment using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

```
<article>
    <articleInfo>
        <journalCode>ABC</journalCode>
        <articleNo>456</articleNo>
    </articleInfo>
    <body>
        <heading><!--This article contain 1 heading-->Heading 1</heading>
        <p>α-index</p>
        <p>This is para 2</p>
        <p>This is para 3</p>
        <p>This is para 4</p>
        <p>This is para 5</p>
    </body>
</article>
```

how can i change the comment text using xslt
also i want to replace the a-index to α thanks in advance

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>



<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
 xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes"
 xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xs xdt err fn">

 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="*|comment()">

  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  <xsl:comment>This heading was the only 1 heading in article</xsl:comment>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: i want my output to be like this  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article>
 <articleInfo>
  <journalCode>ABC</journalCode>
  <articleNo>456</articleNo>
 </articleInfo>
 <body>
  <heading><!--This heading was the only 1 heading in article-->Heading 1</heading>
  <p>&alpha;-index</p>
  <p>This is para 2</p>
  <p>This is para 3</p>
  <p>This is para 4</p>
  <p>This is para 5</p>
 </body>
</article>

Comment: Actually, you can edit your question to put your code and output. Btw, what is `&alpha;` in your expected output. It is not a proper escaped character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | *">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[contains(.,'α-index')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., 'α-index', 'index 1')"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment()">
    <xsl:comment>This heading was the only 1 heading in article</xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And you can change the second template(matching text()) as per your requirement.